# How to create a role with view access permission to only a single repository in nexus OSS?

Tags: nexus

I created a repository in nexus oss . So it automatically created a privilege to view that repo . Now I created a role to map having this privilege and assigned it  to a user . But still the user is unable to view that repo .

Is that I have to create additional privileges ?

Try outs : 
   Then I created a privilege with that repository target .and added it to the role . Now 
I am able to search for the repository target . But I get error

Nexus returned an error: ERROR 403: Forbidden .

I am unable to browse the path fully in the pane below the GAV search pane [image]

Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution , because the pattern that I gave in repository target was just

> .*/com/company/projectA/.*

what happened was it was unable to view each folder com , com/company , com/company/projectA separately . so because of which the UI was unable to be formed

so I changed pattern to

> /|/com/|/com/company/|/com/company/projectA/.*

And it worked .

Thanks